# How to display for loop PHP variable in newline in html table

Tags: php

I want to display forloop value in newline in html table

```php
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$i++."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['instructorname']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['batchname']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['fromdate']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['todate']."</td>";

for ($i = $startdate; $i < $todate; $i++) echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
echo "</tr>";
```

I want to display each  `$i` value in newline but it appears in same line.

Comment: if you need all value in same td then use this
echo '<td>'; for($i=$startdate;$i<$todate;$i++){ echo $i.'\n' ;} echo '</td>';

Comment: you can use <br> tag

Answer (score 1):

Just echo `<br/>` to make a new line

```
echo '<td>', $startdate;

for($i = $startdate + 1; $i < $todate; $i++)
    echo '<br/>', $i;

echo '</td>';
```

FYI use comma in echo statement is better than dot

Answer (score 0):

Just added in your code

concat "\n" to the front of the statement

```
echo "\n" ."<td>" . $row['instructorname'] . "</td>";
echo "\n" ."<td>" . $row['batchname'] . "</td>";
```

I hope it's helps you.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are going to use "\n" for some reason better use PHP_EOL constant because on different system new line character can be different. For example also "\r" and PHP_EOL already have character suitable for your current system